# What is the benefit of tenses when time period can be pinned down by adverbs?

Tags: verbs, adverbs

In language like English and German, there is two ways to indicate time period. One is with conjugation and the other with time adverbs. To my understanding, the adverbs allow for exact pinning down of the time period. Some other languages like Indonesian have no tenses, only adverbs.

I think the structure of Indonesian is best due to simplicity. To expand my view point, I  ask, what are the benefits of having both adverbs and tenses like in a language?

Comment: I think it's a little unclear what you mean by "one is with conjugation and the other with past". Can you give an example of a sentence in both forms?

Comment: Tried my best to elaborate @Tristan

Comment: an example sentence in both forms would be the best way to clarify

Comment: It's very difficult to answer questions about "what are the advantages/disadvantages of having such and such a feature in X language?" Languages are (usually) not designed or consciously shaped: they just happen. What is the advantage of (most) IE languages indexing the subject on the verb, of Semitic and Kartvelian languages of indexing the subject and the object on the verb, of many languages' grammatically distinguishing singular from plural, of some languages marking the kind of information expressed (personal experience vs hearsay vs universal truth vs conjecture)? Languages differ.

Comment: Also, _tense_ is very different from 'time period'. Children are taught that tense has to do with time, but only sometimes.  _He hammers nails_ doesn't mean he's doing it now, even though it's "present tense". The purpose (and therefore the "benefit", as far as there is one) of tense varies from language to language, and if they don't meet that purpose, they're dropped. That appears to have happened some time ago in the Germanic languages, with the result that English, like German, has only two tenses - present and past - and dozens of other constructions like Perfect or Progressive.

Comment: @ColinFine I disagree. The advantages/disadvantages are clear. Agreement (of all forms) increases redundancy. This is good because it allows for more reliable decoding by the listener over a lossy medium, but in doing so increases the (segmental) length of the signal. It's a balancing act to maintain rate of decoded information. Including pronominal arguments in the verb rather than as independent pronouns is less clear though. Likewise different methods of describing past events typically have slightly different nuance, which is their utility

Comment: @jlawler that's mostly a matter of how the forms are labelled. The English "present tense" isn't a present tense in the normal sense of that term (except for certain verbs, notably copulas and verbs of sensation). And from a linguistic POV, tense _is_ only to do with location on the timeline, it's just that many (most?) languages have verb forms colloquially referred to as "tenses" that also incorporate aspect/mood/etc

Comment: @Tristan: in the abstract, I agree with you. I suppose I was reacting to a question which to me read "Why do some languages do this stupid thing when Indonesian manages fine without it?"

Comment: yeah that's understandable and doesn't seem like an incorrect reading of the question

Comment: And Indonesian has tense particles, too, though they're optional. _Ka_ is past and _akan_ (lit 'want', like English _will_) is future. Present is unmarked, like English (except for 3rd singular -s, which is going away in many dialects).

Comment: Language is a biological system and artefact, and there is a payoff between energy and time on the one hand and informativity on the other. Adverbs and other temporal adjuncts  allow for greater specificity and thus greater informativity. On the other hand inflection uses less resources in terms of both time and effort (in English, for example, the past tense inflection usually doesn't even increase the number of syllables and usually only adds a single phoneme). It's all swings and roundabouts. Languages seem to end up needing the same amount of time to convey the same information.

Comment: Dahl and Velupillai 2013 (WALS, The past tense) give the following example from Indonesian, *Air itu dingin.* ‘The water is/was cold.’  Do I understand it correctly, that without temporal adverbs this sentence is ambiguous?

Answer (score 4):

The benefit of tenses compared to compositional phrases is analogous to the benefit of having words like "horse; run; green". We could do without such words, instead using a descriptive phrase like "large domesticated quadrupedal mammal used for riding or hauling". The benefit is cognitive economy – we instantly know what thing is referred to when you say "horse", we don't have to think it over (also, we don't have to dig deeper and talk longer to exclude "donkey; mule").

I assume when you say "tense" you mean strictly "eventuality reference time", but there is a broader non-technical use of the term that covers aspect, mood and other event-related concept. The aforementioned benefit holds for all of these concepts and more – you can use a simple element within the verbal phrase to convey specific information. It is very much *like* adverbs and other open-ended expressions, but by being conventionalized and part of a closed class, greater expressive precision can be achieved more efficiently. Or, you can *avoid* precision, if that's your goal and the language allows it. I English, you can say "I saw a coyote", and without any further explanation this could mean that you just saw it, or you saw it earlier today, or yesterday, or 2 days ago, or a week+ ago. In Logoori, you can't be so vague: their tense system commits you to certain distances in the past.

You always have the option of a phrasal construction, if you want to step outside the bounds of what a tense-system in a particular language conveys, just as you can eliminate many nouns, verbs and adjectives and use a paraphrase.

Answer (score 2):

In English, time period can be conveyed by saying "Tom punched Marty." To do this with adverbs, you'd say "Tom had, in the past, punched Marty." That's wordy and still uses the conjugation. In english, the suffixes "-ed" and "'ll*" allow for future and past tense. To pin the time *exactly*, one could theoretically construct a wordier sentence ("Tom punched Marty at five PM on Sunday the twenty-seventh of November 2022"), it's simpler to use a one-phoneme / two-grapheme conjugation to give tense information, though it isn't as exact as the information you'd get in Indonesisan. Neither system is truly "better" or "more efficient," rather both systems value different things. English prefers ambiguity to complexity, and Indonesian prefers the converse.

**'ll* is technically a contraction used to replace the adverb "will," not a morpheme of any sort. However, colloquially, in some dialects of English it is used to form the future tense.

Comment: Well, that’s English, English uses tenses.  There are languages where there are adverbs instead of tense.

Answer (score 2):

There are no benefits, net.  Both are roughly equally dense and expressive.

This is rather like the benefits of pronouns vs. verb inflections, or prepositions and postpositions vs. noun inflections.

For more, read about language typology and the language cycle theory.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_typology

> R. M. W. Dixon (1998) theorizes that languages normally evolve in a cycle from fusional to analytic to agglutinative to fusional again.

No language is perfectly representative of one typology, they are more towards one corner or the other.

For example, though German has tenses, spoken German uses adverbs instead of tenses far more than English does.  There are many situations where English requires past progressive or present progressive or future tense where even standard German accepts just past tense or present tense and, if needed for clarity, an adverb.